# KStatusNotifierItem not working in newer versions of KDE 4

Tags: python, pyqt, kde-plasma, pykde

I have an applet that uses KStatusNotifierItem of PyKDE4. In Arch Linux with versions as such (Qt - 4.8.4, KDE Development Platform - 4.9.5) taken from kde4-config -v, it works.

However, in Kubuntu 12.10 with versions (Qt - 4.8.3, KDE Development Platform - 4.9.98), it's not working. Could anyone point me to how i can debug it?

Here's an example of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, QString
from PyKDE4.kdeui import KStatusNotifierItem


App = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Notifier(QObject):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    self.tray = KStatusNotifierItem(self)
    self.tray.setCategory(KStatusNotifierItem.Communications)
    self.tray.setIconByName(QString("/usr/share/icons/oxygen/16x16/categories/applications-internet.png"))
    self.tray.setStatus(KStatusNotifierItem.Active)
    self.tray.setToolTipIconByName(QString("/usr/share/icons/oxygen/16x16/categories/applications-internet.png"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  notifer = Notifier()
  App.exec_()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also reported this in [bugs.kde.org,](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=314595) and they have found a solution. Basically the line `self.tray = KStatusNotifierItem(self)` needs to be changed to `self.tray = KStatusNotifierItem("someID", self)`.